# How to see if a post on a FB page is updated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I am using the `graph api` to get data about pages and the posts in the pages.
When a post is published, it gets liked, commented upon and shared over time. When I read the data next time how can I get the posts that have those changes alone?

Comment: I am not failing at anything particularly.

Comment: My issue is that , is it possible to just take those posts from a page which has newly added likes or comments

Comment: Maybe look into _real-time updates_.

Comment: Yeah, i ve known about real time updates, but that approach proves to be a bit costly fro my applicaton.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is really to set up a server to receive real time updates. Any other way would mean polling facebook endpoints.  At a certain point, a single user access token would be rate limited, and would block you from making a call for a certain amount of time.  Also, there would be more work to compare each post to the one you stored to see if anything has changed.

Really the most efficient way is to use real time updates in which you set up an endpoint on your server to receive messages from facebook whenever something on a page (or user) has changed.  If cost of keeping a server running is your roadblock, I would recommend to setup a free Parse.com account in which you can set up a server to handle Facebook's incoming requests and act on that.

I hope that makes sense!  More information on realtime updates here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.2